# Prisma client is not working with next js serverless when deployed over aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, serverless, prisma

I am using next js "12.1.6" and prisma version "^3.15.2". When I deploy my app over vercels, It works very smoothly. But, When I try to upload the same app over aws using serverless, it does't work. Below is my serverless.yml file.

```
myNextApp:
  component: "@sls-next/serverless-component"
```

My next.config.js file contains configuration for db connection.

```
DATABASE_URL:"mysql://***:***@***:3306/****"
```

If I remove prisma client from my app, the app works with aws as well, but it doesn't work with prisma client.

I have tried below solutions which did not work.

[LINK TO GIT REPOSITORY](https://github.com/millsp/prisma-serverless-nextjs)

Below is the serverless.yml code.

```
yourProjectName:
  component: "@sls-next/serverless-component@1.19.0"
  inputs:
    minifyHandlers: true
    build:
      postBuildCommands:
        - PDIR=node_modules/.prisma/client/;
          LDIR=.serverless_nextjs/api-lambda/;
          if [ "$(ls -A $LDIR)" ]; then
            mkdir -p $LDIR$PDIR;
            cp "$PDIR"query-engine-rhel-* $LDIR$PDIR;
            cp "$PDIR"schema.prisma $LDIR$PDIR;
          fi;
        - PDIR=node_modules/.prisma/client/;
          LDIR=.serverless_nextjs/default-lambda/;
            if [ "$(ls -A $LDIR)" ]; then
              mkdir -p $LDIR$PDIR;
              cp "$PDIR"query-engine-rhel-* $LDIR$PDIR;
              cp "$PDIR"schema.prisma $LDIR$PDIR;
          fi;
```

when I run 'serverless' with above code (my OS is Windows 10), it says "PDIR is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

If I try to put ".prisma/client" folder in '.serverless_nextjs/api-lambda/' and '.serverless_nextjs/default-lambda/', it automatically get disappear after I run serverless.

This is the [url](https://github.com/amitleuva1987/full-stack-nextjs-with-prisma) to my repo which works fine with "vercels" but not working with "aws serverless"

Comment: Hey Amit, could you try [this solution](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/6032#issuecomment-837281151)? If this does not work, could you provide some more information about your problem? Error logs and/or a reproduction (that we can test out) would go a long way in identifying the problem.

Comment: @TasinIshmam, thanks for looking at this issue. I already tried the solution you suggested. I have created an issue in the same repo url which you provided. below is my issue [url](https://github.com/millsp/prisma-serverless-nextjs/issues/2).  This is the [url](https://github.com/amitleuva1987/full-stack-nextjs-with-prisma) to my repo from where you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have also edited the post and try explain thing in better way.

Comment: Hi @amit, I'm extremely sorry for the miscommunication, but could you kindly create the issue (as a bug report) in the [Prisma repository](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new/choose). 

Kindly link the repository in the issue as well. Additionally, the repository does not provide any instructions for how to reproduce the problem in AWS serverless. Could you mention the steps to do that as well?

Comment: @TasinIshmam, I have created an issue with the prisma repository, This is the [url](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/14233).  I have also add the steps to reproduce the problem in my repo, readme.md.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put below lines in your serverless.yml. This will work for next js 12 or >12, Prisma >= 4

```
inputs:
   useServerlessTraceTarget: true
```